# Sharepoint Onilne Workflow - Completed instances are automatically deleted after 30 days

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, designer

WE have a workflow set up on  a task list and for some of the instances the users are unable to update the status and get the message that "We cant find the workflow. Completed instances are automatically cleaned after 30 days. 
Is there a workaround for this issue. I tried searching the azzure timer jobs but that option is not visible. 
[image]